# How can I force XBMC to delete a file when removing it from the library?

Tags: windows-7, kodi

I'm using XBMC on Windows 7 with the default skin. Lately I can not delete the video files. When pressing <kbd>DEL</kbd>, a confirmation popup comes up, click yes, but the file remains there.

A week ago it was only frequent, I was able to delete some files, but now it happens every time. I can delete the files from Total Commander and Explorer. It does not matter if the file was ever opened by XBMC or not.

What should I do?